# Alternatives to inheritance for polymorphic behavior for data in database?

Tags: inheritance, orm, polymorphism, composition

I am thinking of designing a website where people can enter their aliases for games they played in the past and they can search for others around the same time period. FWIW I don't care if it exists already, I am in it for the design exercise.

I was thinking how I'd design it, and I wanted to do Django or Flask/SQLAlchemy, and it seems the natural domain objects are:

```
# pseudocode

interface/ABC Alias {
    datetime start_datetime;
    datetime end_datetime;
    Game game;
    string handle; // could be string[] aliases
}
```

Different games have different specific columns, so World of Warcraft has a Server name, a faction, a guild names. Runescape might have a guild name or a world. Guild Wars 2 has Worlds (and maybe some other stuff, I've never played it).

```
# amended

interface/ABC Alias {
    datetime start_datetime;
    datetime end_datetime;
    Game game;
    string handle; // could be string[] aliases
    json game_specific_stuff
}
```

The above is how I'd design it, but I was wondering what alternatives there are. I could have a concrete type to represent each game, I could use composition and have each concrete Type have an `Alias` object.

Perhaps polymorphism isn't needed at all since I probably don't need to do anything with their derived classes doing anything at once. They're just PODOs, so no real behavior that I can think of. Suppose they did have behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Data inheritance has nothing to do with behavior. It’s just the act of tacking on new fields without changing the position of old fields. This way the old fields can be used by old code that expects them to be in their old positions.

Behavior inheritance, and more generally, polymorphism, is really about doing the same thing with function pointers (virtual methods) rather than data fields. But that’s what happens under the covers. Most languages don’t require that you know that. They handle this for you. Either through the languages inheritance keyword / operator or through composition.

But your question seems to want to peek under the covers. So I’ll just say that the similarity between data and behavioral inheritance is about layout. So long as it’s single inheritance we’re talking about it just means laying out the old stuff the same way in the new stuff.

With multiple inheritance you need some way to know which parent you’re in. Can’t just do that by keeping the old position because parents can disagree about what goes where.

That’s true with data or function pointers. But if it’s under the covers you don’t have to deal with it.